# footmisc has to be loaded after setspace - Why?

Tags: packages, setspace, footmisc

If `footmisc` package is loaded before the `setspace` package, then it doesn't work. Though I don't need a work around, since this is easy to incorporate in a document, I just thought that I should share this. If anyone knows the reason behind this, it will be interesting to know (unless there is a mistake in MWE).

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[hmargin={2cm,7cm}]{geometry}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{5cm}
%
\usepackage{setspace}
%
\usepackage[side]{footmisc}
%
\begin{document}
   Tedius line of text for the main body.\footnote{This is a respectable line   of drab footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both packages change the meaning of `\@footnotetext`. Each one undoes the redefinition performed by the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`footmisc` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/footmisc) describes its interactions with various other packages, including `setspace`. This quote is from section 2:

> The `setspace` package modifies the way line spacing is calculated in
>   footnotes. `Footmisc` knows about this, and preserves the change.
>   However, you must load `setspace` before `footmisc`.

If you load `setspace` last, then `footmisc` cannot undo the changes made by it.